# How much time did an user logged in?

Tags: sql

Supposed I have the following data of users, each time they logged in and logged out:

```
User   LogType   Date 
1      In        2018-10-05 13:18:26.900
1      Out       2018-10-05 13:18:54.353
1      In        2018-10-05 13:19:23.637
1      Out       2018-10-05 13:20:03.887
2      In        2018-10-05 13:21:25.887
2      Out       2018-10-05 13:22:01.247
3      In        2018-10-10 18:24:33.867
3      Out       2018-10-10 18:25:35.443
```

How do I create another column illustrating how long an user was logged in for a session? For example, here's what I wish to see:

```
User Type Date                    Duration
1    In   2018-10-05 13:18:26.900
1    Out  2018-10-05 13:18:54.353 2018-10-05 13:18:54.353 - 2018-10-05 13:18:26.900
1    In   2018-10-05 13:19:23.637
1    Out  2018-10-05 13:20:03.887 2018-10-05 13:20:03.887 - 2018-10-05 13:19:23.637
2    In   2018-10-05 13:21:25.887
2    Out  2018-10-05 13:22:01.247 2018-10-05 13:22:01.247 - 2018-10-05 13:21:25.887
3    In   2018-10-10 18:24:33.867
3    Out  2018-10-10 18:25:35.443 2018-10-10 18:25:35.443 - 2018-10-10 18:24:33.867
```

I need this as a sql column(not the string but the time difference). Any tips?

Comment: Will an In always be followed by an Out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the previous "in" using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when logtype = 'In' then date end) over (partition by user order by date) as prev_in_date
from t;
```

If you only want to see this on "out" rows, then use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when logtype = 'Out'
             then max(case when logtype = 'In' then date end) over (partition by user order by date)
        end) as prev_in_date
from t;
```

The calculation for duration depends on the database.